# Where was Rhonda's/AF709's off switch?

Tags: character, my-living-doll

In the TV series *[My Living Doll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Living_Doll)*, Julie Newmar played robot AF709 (supposedly the origin of the name 'Seven of Nine').

I know that she had an OFF switch, but where was it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Beauty Marks on her Back

### [image]

This took some finding but...

[**TVObscurities.com**](http://www.tvobscurities.com/articles/my_living_doll/)

> At first, Bob doesn’t believe Dr. Beckman’s claims that AF 709 is a robot. As proof, Dr. Beckman deactivates her, explaining that the **beauty marks on her back serve as control buttons**. Furthermore, when a cloth is placed over the robot’s eyes, it enters a state similar to human sleep. Dr. Beckman asks Bob to look after the robot for a few days. Realizing that he can’t let the robot out of his sight, he calls his sister Irene (played by Doris Dowling) and asks her to move in with him temporarily to act as a chaperone.